# Failed Loop using while

Tags: java, while-loop

My idea was like this.

1. I have any number(tens number)
2. check the length of number
3. if the length is one then finish
4. if the length more than one (which is two) I want to do a looping procedure until the length of number reaches one.
   so this is the logic
5. if the length of number is more than one (2), I took tens value and one's value of the number.
6. then I add both numbers,
7. check the length of result if still 2 repeat procedure

i.e The number is 38, length is more than 1.
Ten's value is 3 and One's value is 8. I add both of it, 3+8 =11.

11 length is still more than one.
Ten's value is 1 and One's value is 1, add both of it, 1+1=2.

2 length is one. end of looping.

Here is the code I tried but it's failed (infinite loop)

```
hitung = 38
hitungtxt = Integer.toString(hitung);
jumkar2 = hitungtxt.length();

while (jumkar2 > 1) {
    char hita = hitungtxt.charAt(0);
    char hitb = hitungtxt.charAt(1);
    int hitung1=(int)hita;
    int hitung2=(int)hitb;
    hitung=hitung1+hitung2;
    hitungtxt = Integer.toString(hitung);
    jumkar2 = hitungtxt.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
char hita = hitungtxt.charAt(0);
int hitung1=(int)hita;
```

This will get `Ascii value` for that number. If you want to fix this problem try: `int hita = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hitungtxt.charAt(0)));`

So, your final code should be like:

```
    int hitung = 38;
    String hitungtxt = Integer.toString(hitung);
    int jumkar2 = hitungtxt.length();

    while (jumkar2 > 1) {
        int hita = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hitungtxt.charAt(0)));
        int hitb = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hitungtxt.charAt(1)));
        hitung = hita + hitb;

        hitungtxt = Integer.toString(hitung);
        jumkar2 = hitungtxt.length();
    }

    System.out.println(hitungtxt);
```

Hope it helps!